# MySQL - List of cell contents that have matching column

Tags: mysql

I'm way over my head with the SQL query.  I'm capable of showing all of the rows with matching software and could probably sort out how to get the computernames from computerID's but getting the actual required output is just beyond me.
Even posing the question is challenging but here we go.

I have a table that lists computers that have each piece of software.  The computers are identified by a computerID and there is a second table that associates computerID's to computernames.
What I need is a list of computernames that have each piece of software.

Software table

```
----------------------------
| computerID | software    |
----------------------------
|     1      | 7-zip       |
----------------------------
|     1      | winzip      |
----------------------------
|     2      | 7-zip       |
----------------------------
|     2      | chrome      |
----------------------------
|     3      | winzip      |
----------------------------
|     3      | putty       |
----------------------------
```

Computer table

```
-----------------------------
| computerID | computerName |
-----------------------------
|     1      |     PC1      |
-----------------------------
|     2      |     PC2      |
-----------------------------
|     3      |     PC3      |
-----------------------------
```

The required output is:

```
7-zip: PC1, PC2
chrome: PC2
putty: PC3
winzip: PC1, PC3
```

Can someone help put that into a query?

Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat and post a query attempt if you get into difficulty.

Comment: take a look at group_concat function

Comment: You should probably have a software table, then a computer_software table linking the two ids.  This will be more maintainable and quicker in the long run.

Comment: group_concat was just the ticket.  Knowing that I was able to put together the required query.  Thanks kiks73

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take a look at JOINS and AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS, in particular  GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.computerName, ': ', 
       GROUP_CONCAT(B.software)) AS RESULT
FROM Computer A INNER JOIN Software B ON A.computerID = B.computerID
GROUP BY A.computerName
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome.  Thanks so much all.  That was just the kickstart I needed.  The resulting query is:

```
SELECT concat(t1.NAME, ":",
  GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name))
FROM `software` t1 JOIN computers t2 ON t1.computerid=t2.computerid 
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Personally, I think this a poor approach- but I respect that that's a minority opinion

Comment: @GPRS instead of copying and pasting my answer in your answer, you should upvote and mark as correct answer mine!

Comment: I tried to upvote but the system declined.  I did mark as correct though.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Strawberry, why is this a poor approach and what would be better?

Comment: I think issues of data display should be handled in application code.